# Storage Spaces Drives Preventing Update/Install of Windows 10 1903

Tags: windows-10-upgrade, storage-spaces, windows-10-v1809, windows-10-v1903

I have Windows 10 installed on a 1TB SSD, with 6 HDDs (3 or 4 TB) in a storage spaces virtual disk. Some of the HDDs are plugged into SATA slots on the motherboard and some are plugged into a PCI-E SATA card.

I had 1809 installed, and the update to 1903 failed repeatedly, getting stuck on the Windows logo with the rotating circle and requiring a hard reset. Thinking that a clean install would solve the problems, I created a USB drive and a DVD using the media creation tool, but neither would boot completely into the setup. They would generally get to a blue screen with a cursor but nothing else. I eventually got it to boot into Kyhi's recovery drive and then ran the install setup. It worked fine until the install rebooted and it again got stuck on the Windows logo with the rotating circle.

Relying on a suggestion from some forum posts, I tried unplugging all drives but the SSD, and I was able to install 1903 without incident. But, as soon as I plugged in the storage spaces HDDs, it would hang on the Windows logo and rotating circle. Nothing I did, other than disconnecting any HDDs from the motherboard SATA ports, made any difference.

I then got 1809 install media and reinstalled it without incident. The storage spaces drive shows up as completely healthy. I'm really not sure what to even try at this point. I'm leaving it on 1809 for now.

Edit: I did not update to the cumulative patch before reconnecting the storage spaces drives. They have continued working fine after the cumulative patch. I created the 1903 installation media on July 22.

Comment: When you installed 1803, did you update Windows 10, to the current cumulative patch before you plugged your Storage Spaces in? Edit your question instead of replying to this comment. Additionally, when did you make the ISO, I recently installed 1903 and didn’t have a problem on my new machine.

Answer (score 1):

> I had 1809 installed, and the update to 1903 failed repeatedly, getting stuck on the Windows logo with the rotating circle and requiring a hard reset. Thinking that a clean install would solve the problems, I created a USB drive and a DVD using the media creation tool, but neither would boot completely into the setup.

The reason 1903 was failing to install was due to the known issue, [Error attempting to update with an external USB device or memory card attached](https://docs.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/release-information/status-windows-10-1903#532msgdesc), which affected both external and internal storage devices.

> I eventually got it to boot into Kyhi's recovery drive and then ran the install setup. It worked fine until the install rebooted and it again got stuck on the Windows logo with the rotating circle.

The issue you describe is the exact reason Windows 10 version 1903 was blocked until July 11th, 2019 when both external and internal disks were installed in a system other than the system disk.

> Relying on a suggestion from some forum posts, I tried unplugging all drives but the SSD, and I was able to install 1903 without incident. But, as soon as I plugged in the storage spaces HDDs, it would hang on the Windows logo and rotating circle. Nothing I did, other than disconnecting any HDDs from the motherboard SATA ports, made any difference.

It sounds like you might have installed a Windows 10 version 1903 build from before this issue was fixed on July 11th, 2019.  I suspect if you attempted the upgrade today, and made sure you installed KB4505903, you wouldn't have this problem.

> I then got 1809 install media and reinstalled it without incident. The storage spaces drive shows up as completely healthy. I'm really not sure what to even try at this point.

This particular issue only affected Windows 10 version 1903. Eventually, you will have to upgrade to Windows 10 version 1903, that requirement won't happen until 18 months after Windows 10 version 1903 was initially released.

Comment: I didn't even create the installation media until July 22, so that issue should have been resolved. And I never had a USB drive or memory card attached to the computer when the updates were attempted. Obviously, a USB drive was attached when I used it as the install media, but not when I used the DVD.

Comment: @JamesAaron - The issue affected both external and internal drives.  So the existence of your Storage Spaces would have caused the issue.  Just because you didn't create the installation media until July 22nd, 2019 does not mean it was the most recent media.  The fact you did not install the cumulative update, which resolves the problem before connecting the Storage Spaces drives, indicates your issue was likely due to this resolved issue.

Comment: So the media creation tool downloaded an outdated version of Windows? I understand the problem affects both internal and external drives, but you have to actually have at least some external drives for it to happen. I had no external drives.

Comment: The Media Creation Tool would indeed download whatever was the current ISO at the time, if it had not been updated when you downloaded it (or you choose not to the option to update the image), you would have installed an older build of Windows 10 version 1903.   If my answer does not answer your question, I would rather just delete, then continue this discussion.

Comment: @JamesAaron - You indicated in your question that once you disconnected your Storage Spaces drives, you were able to install Windows 10 version 1903, but once you connected them you had a problem.  You also indicated you did not install the cumulative update that resolves the problem with both internal and external drives before you had the problem again after connecting Storage Spaces.  *Your Storage Spaces drives were causing the conflict*, which matches the issue that was reported, due to the fact both external and internal drives cause the problem.

Comment: I was referring to the 1809 cumulative update. When. I installed 1903, I checked windows update and it said there were no updates. I then reconnected the drives, and it would not boot.

Comment: 1809 is not a cumulative update nor did Windows 10 version 1809 have this reported problem with external and internal drives.  KB4505903 only applies to 1903 not 1809.\